# Adding a theme to shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

According to the [Shiny documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/): "In your ui.R, use the theme argument to bootstrapPage, fluidPage, navbarPage, or fixedPage. The value should be shinytheme(""); for example, shinytheme("cerulean")."

I am trying to add a theme to a UI page that has none of the above specified pages. No matter where I add the `theme = shinytheme("superhero")` within the UI, I get an error. Any suggestions for where I should be adding this theme??

```
    dat_in <- read_table2("term_year_fct   mean    value   Program name    subgroup_fct    Year
Summer&Fall2017 7.647482014 139 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    1
Winter&Spring2018   6.34741784  213 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    2
Summer&Fall2018 7.166666667 246 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    3
Winter&Spring2019   7.759036145 249 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    4
Summer&Fall2019 11.97986577 149 STEMLearningCenter  AllUsers    AllUsers    5
Summer&Fall2017 8.769230769 104 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   1
Winter&Spring2018   8.563380282 142 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   2
Summer&Fall2018 9.51497006  167 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   3
Winter&Spring2019   9.675824176 182 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   4
Summer&Fall2019 12.44680851 141 STEMLearningCenter  STEMUsers   STEMUsers   5
")




library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel(""),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_prog"),
    
    uiOutput("choose_name"),
    br(),
  ),
  
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  # Drop down selection to chose the program 
  output$choose_prog <- renderUI({
    selectInput("program", "STEM Program", unique(dat_in$Program))
  })
  
  output$choose_name <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    # if(is.null(input$program))
    #   return()
    
    # Get the program with the appropriate names
    dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program)
    name_options <- unique(dat$name)
    
    # Create the check boxes & select them all by default 
    checkboxGroupInput("names", "select category of interest", 
                       choices = name_options,
                       selected = name_options)
    
  })
  
  # dat <- reactive({
  #   dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program & name==input$names)
  #   return(dat)
  # })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    # Output the plot
    
    dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program & name==input$names)
    
    # head(dat)
    # head(dat)
    dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Year,y = value,fill = subgroup_fct)) + 
      geom_area(aes(colour = subgroup_fct, fill = subgroup_fct), color = "white", position = "identity") +
      ggtitle(unique(dat$Program))+ 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#285560", "#57a6b9", "#8fa13a")) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 300), expand = c(0, 20)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1:5),
                         labels = str_wrap(levels(program_components$term_year_fct),
                                           width = 15)) + 
      xlab("") + 
      ylab("Count of \nUnique Users\n") + 
      
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "All Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1, show.legend = FALSE)  +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "STEM Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "Frequent Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) 

    
    
  })
  
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with `fluidPage()`.  Not sure why it does not work with `pageWithSidebar()` for your code.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),  # shinythemes::themeSelector(), #
  
  headerPanel("Test App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choose_prog"),
      
      uiOutput("choose_name"),
      br(),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  # Drop down selection to chose the program 
  output$choose_prog <- renderUI({
    selectInput("program", "STEM Program", unique(dat_in$Program))
  })
  
  output$choose_name <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    # if(is.null(input$program))
    #   return()
    
    # Get the program with the appropriate names
    req(input$program)
    dat <- subset(dat_in, Program == input$program)
    name_options <- unique(dat$name)
    
    # Create the check boxes & select them all by default 
    checkboxGroupInput("names", "select category of interest", 
                       choices = name_options,
                       selected = name_options)
    
  })
  
  # dat <- reactive({
  #   dat <-subset(dat_in, Program == input$program & name==input$names)
  #   return(dat)
  # })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    # Output the plot
    req(input$program,input$names)
    dat <-subset(dat_in, Program %in% input$program & name %in% input$names)
    
    # head(dat)
    # head(dat)
    dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Year,y = value,fill = subgroup_fct)) + 
      geom_area(aes(colour = subgroup_fct, fill = subgroup_fct), color = "white", position = "identity") +
      ggtitle(unique(dat$Program))+ 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#285560", "#57a6b9", "#8fa13a")) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 300), expand = c(0, 20)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1:5),
                         labels = str_wrap(unique(dat$term_year_fct),
                                           width = 15)) + 
      xlab("") + 
      ylab("Count of \nUnique Users\n") + 
      
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "All Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1, show.legend = FALSE)  +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "STEM Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
      geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "Frequent Users", value, "")), 
                hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, show.legend = FALSE) 
    
    
    
  })
  
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please try your method using my code example (I realized there was a bug in it, I just fixed it)!

Comment: @NewBee, please check the updated code.  Your code still had some minor issues.